# Excel VBA .Saveas() function to preseve formating

Tags: vba, excel, save-as

I'm trying to use the below saveas() function to output an excel worksheet to a xltext file. the file is generated fine but numbers with a special formatting of #,###.00. are output as "1,000.00" rather than just 1,000.00. How can I remove these double quotes.

```
Dim tab_output_line, tab_output_head, tab_source As String
Dim File_Location As String

tab_output_line = "Upload_PO_LineItem"
tab_source = "PBOOK"

File_Location = Sheets(tab_source).Range("S5").Value

Sheets(tab_output_line).Select
ChDir File_Location
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    File_Location + tab_output_line + ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText, _
    CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: You would need to use a different delimiter, like tab. If your data has commas in it, using commas as delimiters it going to cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is making a **tab-delimited** file.  Cells that contain commas *(even as formatted)* are being "protected" by being enclosed in double quotes.

To avoid this "protection", try code like this:

```
Sub tony2()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, Record As String
    Dim M As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Close #2
    Open "C:\Users\Garys\desktop\tony.txt" For Output As #2

    For i = 1 To N
        Record = ""
        M = Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For j = 1 To M
            Record = Record & vbTab & Cells(i, j).Text
        Next j
        Record = Mid(Record, 2)
        Print #2, Record
    Next i
    Close #2
End Sub
```

Input:

[image]

and output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks that Solved it